# Dynamically loaded thumbnail image shows other thumbnails full size image instead of its own (using javascript hover over effect)

Tags: php, html, css, javascript, mysql

my level of knowledge: i have just started teaching myself PHP and Dreamweaver after watching a video tutorial on how to build data-driven websites using dreamweaver 2 days ago.

my aim: to create a page which is basically a dynamic table which has 6 columns and 20 rows

```
column1        | column2         | column3   | column4  | column5 | column 6
50px thumbnail | ad post subject | gender    | location | age     | date of post
  "                 "                "           "         "           "
  "                 "                "           "         "           "
  "                 "                "           "         "           "
  "                 "                "           "         "           "
```

my problem: so far i have successfully managed to populate the table by pulling the rows from mysql db and the thumbnail in column1 is also dynamically loading. the problem is, because the 50pxby50px thumbnail (which is actually a much larger jpg in the /images folder but being resized by CSS or HTML i think) is quite small and so i have decided that i want the image to be enlarged when user hovers cursor over it. i found a javascript script which achieves this very nicely here - http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex4/imagetooltip.htm i have managed to configure all that correctly following the instructions. but i did need to experiment a bit as the examples given arent for dynamic images (example is `tooltips[0]=["images/examplepic.jpg"]` whereas my case is like this

```
tooltips[0]=["images/<?php echo $row_qDisplayAds['image1']; ?>"]
```

after managing to figure out what the correct path and echo syntax should be i tried previewing it in browser and it worked i.e when i hovered over the thumbnail in the first row a full sized version shows of the thumbnail in row 1. however, when i hover over the thumbnail in row 2 it shows the full size version of thumbnail in row 1 aswell. as youve probably guessed when hovering over all the other thumbnails in all 20 rows of the table the same full size pic is shown. so the only thumbnail which shows its corresponding full size image upon hovering is row 1. all other thumbnails dont show their own full size image and instead show the first rows thumbnail in full size. any ideas what i need to do to make each thumbnail show its own corresponding full size version as i have no idea how to go about this and as its such a specific problem its impossible to find any tutorials on how to achieve this.

this is the full code of my index.php page.

```
<?php virtual('/myfirstsite/Connections/conn_firstdynamic.php'); ?>
<?php
if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
  if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
    $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
  }

  $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

  switch ($theType) {
    case "text":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;    
    case "long":
    case "int":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "double":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "date":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "defined":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
      break;
  }
  return $theValue;
}
}

mysql_select_db($database_conn_firstdynamic, $conn_firstdynamic);
$query_qDisplayAds = "SELECT category, topic, `date`, age, location, image1 FROM ads ORDER BY idno DESC";
$qDisplayAds = mysql_query($query_qDisplayAds, $conn_firstdynamic) or die(mysql_error());
$row_qDisplayAds = mysql_fetch_assoc($qDisplayAds);
$totalRows_qDisplayAds = mysql_num_rows($qDisplayAds);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ddimgtooltip.css" />


</head>

<body>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    var ddimgtooltip={

        tiparray:function(){
            var tooltips=[]
            //define each tooltip below: tooltip[inc]=['path_to_image', 'optional desc', optional_CSS_object]
            //For desc parameter, backslash any special characters inside your text such as apotrophes ('). Example: "I\'m the king of the world"
            //For CSS object, follow the syntax: {property1:"cssvalue1", property2:"cssvalue2", etc}

            tooltips[0]=["images/<?php echo $row_qDisplayAds['image1']; ?>"]

            return tooltips //do not remove/change this line
        }(),

        tooltipoffsets: [20, -30], //additional x and y offset from mouse cursor for tooltips

        //***** NO NEED TO EDIT BEYOND HERE

        tipprefix: 'imgtip', //tooltip ID prefixes

        createtip:function($, tipid, tipinfo){
            if ($('#'+tipid).length==0){ //if this tooltip doesn't exist yet
                return $('<div id="' + tipid + '" class="ddimgtooltip" />').html(
                    '<div style="text-align:center"><img src="' + tipinfo[0] + '" /></div>'
                    + ((tipinfo[1])? '<div style="text-align:left; margin-top:5px">'+tipinfo[1]+'</div>' : '')
                    )
                .css(tipinfo[2] || {})
                .appendTo(document.body)
            }
            return null
        },

        positiontooltip:function($, $tooltip, e){
            var x=e.pageX+this.tooltipoffsets[0], y=e.pageY+this.tooltipoffsets[1]
            var tipw=$tooltip.outerWidth(), tiph=$tooltip.outerHeight(), 
            x=(x+tipw>$(document).scrollLeft()+$(window).width())? x-tipw-(ddimgtooltip.tooltipoffsets[0]*2) : x
            y=(y+tiph>$(document).scrollTop()+$(window).height())? $(document).scrollTop()+$(window).height()-tiph-10 : y
            $tooltip.css({left:x, top:y})
        },

        showbox:function($, $tooltip, e){
            $tooltip.show()
            this.positiontooltip($, $tooltip, e)
        },

        hidebox:function($, $tooltip){
            $tooltip.hide()
        },


        init:function(targetselector){
            jQuery(document).ready(function($){
                var tiparray=ddimgtooltip.tiparray
                var $targets=$(targetselector)
                if ($targets.length==0)
                    return
                var tipids=[]
                $targets.each(function(){
                    var $target=$(this)
                    $target.attr('rel').match(/\[(\d+)\]/) //match d of attribute rel="imgtip[d]"
                    var tipsuffix=parseInt(RegExp.$1) //get d as integer
                    var tipid=this._tipid=ddimgtooltip.tipprefix+tipsuffix //construct this tip's ID value and remember it
                    var $tooltip=ddimgtooltip.createtip($, tipid, tiparray[tipsuffix])
                    $target.mouseenter(function(e){
                        var $tooltip=$("#"+this._tipid)
                        ddimgtooltip.showbox($, $tooltip, e)
                    })
                    $target.mouseleave(function(e){
                        var $tooltip=$("#"+this._tipid)
                        ddimgtooltip.hidebox($, $tooltip)
                    })
                    $target.mousemove(function(e){
                        var $tooltip=$("#"+this._tipid)
                        ddimgtooltip.positiontooltip($, $tooltip, e)
                    })
                    if ($tooltip){ //add mouseenter to this tooltip (only if event hasn't already been added)
                        $tooltip.mouseenter(function(){
                            ddimgtooltip.hidebox($, $(this))
                        })
                    }
                })

            }) //end dom ready
        }
    }

    //ddimgtooltip.init("targetElementSelector")
    ddimgtooltip.init("*[rel^=imgtip]")
    </script>

    <table id="noticeboard">
      <?php do { ?>
        <tr  class="rowheight">
          <td class="cellheight"><img src="images/<?php echo $row_qDisplayAds['image1']; ?>" alt="" rel='imgtip[0]' style='width:50px;height:50px'/></td>
          <td class="cellheight"><?php echo $row_qDisplayAds['subject']; ?></td>
          <td class="cellheight"><?php echo $row_qDisplayAds['gender']; ?></td>
          <td class="cellheight"><?php echo $row_qDisplayAds['age']; ?></td>
          <td class="cellheight"><?php echo $row_qDisplayAds['location']; ?></td>
          <td class="cellheight"><?php echo $row_qDisplayAds['date']; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php } while ($row_qDisplayAds = mysql_fetch_assoc($qDisplayAds)); ?>
    </table>


    </body>
    </html>
    <?php
    mysql_free_result($qDisplayAds);
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to loop through the data and assign the images to the tooltip for each index

```
tiparray:function(){
        var tooltips=[];

        <?php 
        $index = 0;
        do { 
        ?>
        tooltips[<?php echo $index++;?>]=["images/<?php echo $row_qDisplayAds['image1']; ?>"];
        <?php 
        } while ($row_qDisplayAds = mysql_fetch_assoc($qDisplayAds)); 
        mysql_data_seek($qDisplayAds,0);
        ?>

        return tooltips //do not remove/change this line
    }(),
```

Additionally, you also need to reset the internal data pointer(back to row 1) for your mysql recordset since you be using it again using mysql_data_seek.

You also need to apply the link between the thumbnails to the correct full screen version. Do this.

```
<table id="noticeboard">
  <?php 
    $index = 0;
    while ($row_qDisplayAds = mysql_fetch_assoc($qDisplayAds)) { ?>
    <tr  class="rowheight">
      <td class="cellheight"><img src="images/<?php echo $row_qDisplayAds['image1']; ?>" alt="" rel='imgtip[<?php echo $index++;?>]' style='width:50px;height:50px'/></td>
      <td class="cellheight"><?php echo $row_qDisplayAds['subject']; ?></td>
      <td class="cellheight"><?php echo $row_qDisplayAds['gender']; ?></td>
      <td class="cellheight"><?php echo $row_qDisplayAds['age']; ?></td>
      <td class="cellheight"><?php echo $row_qDisplayAds['location']; ?></td>
      <td class="cellheight"><?php echo $row_qDisplayAds['date']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php }; ?>
</table>
```

The javascript code handles the linking. All you need to do is update the rel='imgtip[0]' to count up from 0 to 19 for your 20 images.

Comment: Hi Eugene, thanks for reviewing my question/code. Unfortunately it didnt solve the issue and i have no idea why. As i mentioned before i have very very basic knowledge which i have just learned by watching some 10min video tutorials from lynda etc. Also all the code was generated by Dreamweaver cs 5.5 not hand coded at all. all i did was paste the javascript code directly into the index.php file, which got it half working at least whereas before when it was an external .js file linking to the index.php it wasnt working at all for some reason (which is what the instructions suggested).

Comment: Also, by the way i noticed that you put a `;` after the `var tooltips=[]` was that a mistake? either way i tried it with and without it at the end and made no difference still didnt work.

Comment: Having the ; at the end tells javascript that the statement ends here. In javascript, ; can be omitted if you end every statement with a new line. But omitting this can leave a room for careless mistake. I have edited the code. Try again and see if it works

Comment: Hi, just tried literally replacing


`tiparray:function(){
            var tooltips=[]
            //define each tooltip below: tooltip[inc]=['path_to_image', 'optional desc', optional_CSS_object]
            //For desc parameter, backslash any special characters inside your text such as apotrophes ('). Example: "I\'m the king of the world"
            //For CSS object, follow the syntax: {property1:"cssvalue1", property2:"cssvalue2", etc}

            tooltips[0]=["images/<?php echo $row_qDisplayAds['image1']; ?>"]

            return tooltips //do not remove/change this line
        }(),`

Comment: with your exact code `tiparray:function(){
        var tooltips=[];

        <?php 
        $index = 0;
        do { 
        ?>
        tooltips[<?php echo $index;?>]=["images/<?php echo $row_qDisplayAds['image1']; ?>"];
        <?php 
            $index++;
        } while ($row_qDisplayAds = mysql_fetch_assoc($qDisplayAds)); 
        mysql_data_seek($qDisplayAds,0);
        ?>

        return tooltips //do not remove/change this line
    }(),`  and unfortunately still hasnt done the trick. could you explain the logic behind your code so that i can try figure it out too? :)

Comment: Basically, tooltip[0] refers to the first image while tooltip[1] refers to the second and so on.. i just did a loop to output the image for the respective index. Can you explain what is not working? and what behavior are you observing now?

Comment: what should happen is, when i hover over the thumbnail on row1 i should see a full size version of it popup while mouse is on thumbnail. when i hover over thumbnail or row2 i should see full size of the thumbnail on row2. but what is actually happening is, when i hover over all thumbnails from row1 to row20, its always the same full size popup of the thumbnail from row1. so basically no new behaviour. also what i did notice is that when using your code, a new row appears above row1 but without an image or any other data just blank row with a thumbnail size empty space where thumbnail should be

Comment: Do you have a link to your website or something? Do you know how to do a view source of the code? Can you do it and try to debug the javascript?

Comment: its all on localhost root dir xampp htdocs. i viewed source on chrome browser and nothing obvious wrong with the javascript. it just shows `tooltips[0]=["images/row-1-img.jpg"]` .do you think it might be the choice of loop type dreamweaver has chosen to generate i.e the do-while loop instead of a while loop or for each loop etc? also could it be because all 20 images are located in the /images folder? should every row of mysql have its own image folder or is it normal practice to put all images in one folder and php somehow knows which jpg should be the full size for each rows `'image1'` ?

Comment: also forgot to suggest, could it be the lack of `id` as primary keys maybe? im still trying to get my head round database stuff too so its just a thought. but i just cant see from the code how php/javascript can know which jpg to use for row2,row3,row4 when hovering over. how can the tooltip script know out of the 20 jpgs, which one is the correct `image1` ? doesnt there need to be a link between the row2 thumbnail and its respective full size version. how is the javascript going to find the correct `image1` basically?

Comment: Just to clarify, if you view-source, you should be seeing 20 statements of tooltips[0]=["images/row-1-img.jpg"] for your 20 images. (Eg:tooltips[1]=["images/row-2-img.jpg"] and so on...) I've also added new codes for the link between the thumbnail and fullsize version.

Comment: ok its almost working. i.e now when i hover over different thumbnails i dont see the same full size image anymore. however they are all showing the full size version not of their own but of the thumbnail in the row below. e.g i hover over thumbnail in row3 and i see the full size version of the thumbnail of row4, hover over thumb of row4 and you get full size of row5. `tiparray:function(){ var tooltips=[]; tooltips[0]=["images/row-1-img.jpg"]; tooltips[1]=["images/row-2-img.jpg"]; etc etc up to tooltips[19]=["images/row-20-img.jpg"];`

Comment: and also remember i mentioned that for some reason your code creates a blank row before above the first row with no thumbnail or any text in any of the <td> in the row. however when i hover of that row (lets call it row0) eventhough the thumb shows one of those broken link type placeholder images as their is no image src= for it, when you hover over it it shows the full size of the thumb in the row below it which is row1. so this blank row must be disturbing things no? what code is causing that blank row0 to generate before row1 (above it on the noticeboard)?

Comment: Eugene! you did it! its all working 100% correctly now. Thank you so much for all your effort and patience. I hope to help this community as it has helped me once i know enough. so was it because of the do-while loop generated by DW? would you advise not to use dreamweaver in future as it might not generate the most appropriate loops i.e while vs do-while loops etc causing undesired results? i just found website tizag.com and its like w3schools but uses real life useful web examples so helps alot to understand php for anyone out there starting out. also how do i credit you/ give u rep points?

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with dreamweaver. Basically, just had to call $row_qDisplayAds = mysql_fetch_assoc($qDisplayAds)) before we enter each of the loop. This first one was done when you queried your database. Anyway, just give back to the community. PS:i shouldn't have left so many comments so i see you around :)